# Quickblox chat between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, chat, quickblox

I implemented the Quickblox chat on my iOS app and another developer has implemented the same application on the Android app.

When I am talking iOS device to iOS device, everything happens normally, messages are sent, received, listed in my view normally.

When the conversation is between Android device to Android device, all also occurs normally, everything happens perfectly.

The problem is when we try to talk between iOS device and Android device. I get push on my device and when I enter the chat, the message is not always listed on the first time I enter in the chat view. When I'm already in view and I get a message, I need to get out of it and back, so that the message appears, but it appears intermittently.

Is there any configuration needed, conversion, so that the cross-platform chat work properly? This is a known bug?

Thank U!

Comment: My iOS <-> Android cross-platform Quickblox app works seamlessly, so there must be an issue in your code somewhere. If you want to post your code, I can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was occurring in my code.

In iOS, my iPhone was with Settings > General > Date & Time > Time Zone - Automatically switch turned off. My clock was 2 minutes early, then when the list messages with dialog request was being sent, I used [now timeIntervalSince1970], and I didn't receive all the messages, so I had to wait 2 minutes to enter in the chat again, then all the messages were listed. With date, time and  time zone being set up automatically, everything goes fine.

Objective-C Request:

```
NSMutableDictionary *extendedRequest = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
extendedRequest[@"date_sent[lte]"]= @([now timeIntervalSince1970]);
extendedRequest[@"sort_desc"]= @"date_sent";

//get the most recent 100 messages
extendedRequest[@"limit"] = @(100);

[QBChat messagesWithDialogID:self.dialog.ID extendedRequest:extendedRequest delegate:self];
```

In Java, we only had to comment this if:

```
if (messageHistory == null || !messages.get(messages.size() - 1).getId()
.equals(messageHistory.get(messageHistory.size() - 1).getId())) {
  //stuff here
}
```

Now, everything works fine! Thank you for the answers.

Comment: can you share android code show alert or push notification of message receiving if user is not in chat room but logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem. What type of chat you need (private or group)?

Cross-platform chat works normally on Q-municate app. 
Try it (Android side): https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android

Logic for private chat:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/blob/master/Q-municate_core/src/main/java/com/quickblox/q_municate_core/qb/helpers/QBPrivateChatHelper.java

Logic for group chat:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/q-municate-android/blob/master/Q-municate_core/src/main/java/com/quickblox/q_municate_core/qb/helpers/QBMultiChatHelper.java